# Set 3d view angle with view_init in a subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to change the angle in one of the subplots of my figure which is a 3d plot. I do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = f1.add_subplot(2, 1, 1, projection='3d')
ax1.view_init(20, -120)
```

But this doesn't change the view. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `ax = Axes3D(fig)` instead of `add_subplot(2,1,1, projection='3d')`. For me using [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_examples/mplot3d/lines3d_demo.py) demo code, but replacing 'fig.gca(projection='3d')' for `Axes3d(fig)` and then adding `ax.view_init(20,-120)`, it works fine.

Answer (score 8):

After adding

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
```

to your imports, your code should work just fine. Here is the full code I used:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
f1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = f1.add_subplot(2, 1, 1, projection=Axes3D.name)
ax1.view_init(20, -120)
plt.show()
```

This shows:

[image: Figure 1]

And to compare it with another view, with `ax1.view_init(-120, 20)` for example, it shows:

[image: Figure 2]

By the way, a linter might complain about "unused import" `Axes3D`, so instead of `projection='3d'` I wrote `projection=Axes3D.name` in my code above. See [How to directly use Axes3D from matplotlib in standard plot to avoid flake8 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962613/how-to-directly-use-axes3d-from-matplotlib-in-standard-plot-to-avoid-flake8-erro) for further reading.