# How to directly use Axes3D from matplotlib in standard plot to avoid flake8 error

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, flake8

When using the typical 3D plot like so:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
```

`flake8` reports the expected error:

```
./tools.py:62:9: F401 'mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D' imported but unused
```

I know it can be avoided using the `# NOQA` comment. But is there a different way to formulate the projection in the figure so that the Axes3D object is used?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If this is only about actually using the import at least once, you can do

```
ax = fig.gca(projection=Axes3D.name)
```

as `"3d"` is the name of the `Axes3D` class by which it is registered to the projection list.

Comment: Would this be how it is intended to be used, or is it a coincidence that the projection list and class name both use the string `3d`?

Comment: @Jonathan Holvey The projection list contains all registered classes' `name`s. Hence `Axes3D.name` is exactly what to put there if an `Axes3D` is to be created.

Answer (score 0):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
```

However, if I understand the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#getting-started) well, it is not the preferred way anymore since version 1.0.0. I still mention it for completeness.