# add_subplot(111, projection="3d") vs Axes3D(fig)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've seen two ways to create a 3D axes which are

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
```

and

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)
```

I checked out the API of [`figure.add_subplot()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot). And there's no such an option as `'3d'` for the parameter `projection`. Can I assume that `fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")` returns the exact same object as `Axes3D`?

Comment: What exactly you want?

Comment: Yes, you can assume that. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962613/how-to-directly-use-axes3d-from-matplotlib-in-standard-plot-to-avoid-flake8-erro/42972940#42972940).

Answer (score 2):

The default mode for matplotlib is to produce 2D plots. The option **projection** becomes available after import **Axes3D** from mpl_toolkits as the base _axes object will be added. You can read more on this on the [api](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#module-mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d).

> Can I assume that fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d") returns the
>   exact same object as Axes3D?

Yes, but only if Axes3D is imported as mentioned above.

Comment: thanks. where can I find a full list of options for projectoin